# Execute shell command run php in background

Tags: php, shell, background

I run a php script through shell using the following:

```
php script.php
```

How do I type this command in order to run it on the background and also log the output to a file?

I've tried

```
php script.php 2>&1 > out.log
```

But once I close putty, the script stopped.

Answer (score 2):

you can use **nohup** (no hang up)

```
  nohup php script.php 2>&1 > out.log
```

or you use cron or at to run your script in background

Comment: The script is meant for cron but I would like to test it first by manually executing it before I setup the cron.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `&` after the command.

Comment: It seems like even with the &, when I close my putty, the script still stopped. :(

Comment: Yeah you need use nohup as well (as in @donald123's answer). '&' at the end tells the shell "run in the background". Using "nohup" ensures the script ignores the "HUP" signal to quit when you log out.

Answer (score 0):

Try call like this:

```
php script.php 2>&1 > out.log &
```

Comment: It seems like even with the &, when I close my putty, the script still stopped. :(

Comment: Maybe script is end and therefore was stopped.

Comment: Cant be i have 10,000 records on loop

Comment: Very weird. My script looks:
`<?php
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s').' START';
sleep(50);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s').' END';`

and call: `php index.php 2>&1 > log &`

Next I close terminal and run again and list running script by command: `ps afx |grep index`